# How to get (Hrsg.) after each editor with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, formatting

I need to use a Citation style which is oriented at the german DIN1505 (see link for description https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_1505-2#Aufbau_eines_Zitates Sorry only in German).

Here you an find an example for an kind of inbook formatting:

> Schmidt, Kirsten ; Heiman, Bernhard ; Zhou, Ling: Qualität in Speditionen : nicht nur die Termintreue zählt. In: Ziems, Dietrich (Hrsg.) ; Neumann, Gaby (Hrsg.) ; Inderfurth, Karl (Hrsg.) ; Schenk, Michael (Hrsg.) ; Wäscher, Gerhard (Hrsg.) ; Otto-von-Guericke-Universität Magdeburg (Veranst.): Fachtagung Logistikqualität (10. Magdeburger Logistiktagung „Logistik aus technischer und ökonomischer Sicht“ Magdeburg 18. und 19. November 2004). Magdeburg : LOGiSCH, 2004, S. 51–66

As you can notice each editor has the short abbrevation (Hrsg.) (Hrsg. = German for Herausgeber/Editor) behind his name.

I understand the following commands define the editor string:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    byeditor = {(Hrsg\adddot)},    
    editor   = {(Hrsg\adddot)}
}
```

and printing the editors with biblatex should be:

```
\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \setunit{\space}%
     \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}
{}
}
```

How do I have to modify the macro, that "(Hrsg.)" is printed after each editor?
I really enjoy biblatex, but sometimes the complexity is too much, so thank you for your comments on that specific formatting topic.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/domhardt/BibLaTeX-DIN1505

Comment: @ Dr. Manuel Kuehner, this was the basis for the style with some further modifications used at my institute. After researching the DIN1505 I learned, that it recommends to add (editor) after each editor, which I failed to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably easiest to insert the editorstring in the name format directly. To this end we will have to copy all the relevant name format code and modify it  in such a way that it appends the editor string.

```
\newrobustcmd*{\editorsep}{\addspace}
\newrobustcmd*{\editorwrap}{\mkbibparens}

\DeclareNameFormat{family-given-ed}{%
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}%
  \editorsep%
  \editorwrap{%
     \iffieldundef{editortype}
       {\bibstring{editor}}
       {\ifbibxstring{\thefield{editortype}}
          {\bibstring{\thefield{editortype}}}
          {\thefield{editortype}}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

Here `family-given-ed` is a verbose copy of `biblatex.def`'s format `family-given` with only the last lines starting from `\editorsep` added.

We then use this format for editors

```
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{family-given-ed}
```

Finally, we need to get rid of the old way to add the editor string in

```
\renewbibmacro*{editor}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}
```

Done!

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@collection{Katmis2016,
  editor       = {Katmis, Ferhat and Lauter, Valeria and Nogueira, Flavio S.},
  title        = {Alternative Modernities},
  date         = 2001,
  publisher    = {Duke University Press},
  location     = {Durham and London},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newrobustcmd*{\editorsep}{\addspace}
\newrobustcmd*{\editorwrap}{\mkbibparens}

\DeclareNameFormat{family-given-ed}{%
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}}%
  \editorsep%
  \editorwrap{%
     \iffieldundef{editortype}
       {\bibstring{editor}}
       {\ifbibxstring{\thefield{editortype}}
          {\bibstring{\thefield{editortype}}}
          {\thefield{editortype}}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{family-given-ed}

\renewbibmacro*{editor}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\printnames{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}

\begin{document}
    Whatever \cite{Katmis2016,gaonkar}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

then gives

> Gaonkar, Dilip Parameshwar (ed.). *Alternative Modernities.* Durham and London: Duke University Press. isbn: 0-822-32714-7.
>
> Katmis, Ferhat (ed.), Lauter, Valeria (ed.), and Nogueira, Flavio S. (ed.). *Alternative Modernities.* Durham and London: Duke University Press.

Comment: @ moewe, thanks for the MWE, to implement a new macro on family-given seem ike a good way, but when I use your approach it gives me `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \namepartfamily...` which I cannot understand, as \namepartfamily is successful used e.g. in the original family-given. biblatex version I use is v3.3 Right now the result gives me: "....In: (Hrsg.); (Hrsg.); (Hrsg.):...." which is fine except, that it doesn't use the editor names, obviously due to the error.

Comment: @Jäger The code above works with `biblatex` 3.6 (and therefore also with 3.5). You should do an update. If you mus use 3.3 (you really shouldn't it had some other bugs and backwards-compatibility issues) try adding `\nameparts{#1}` as the very first line in `\DeclareNameFormat{family-given-ed}`.

Comment: @Jäger I have updated the answer to be a bit shorter. The solution for 3.3 should still be to add `\nameparts{#1}` to the name format.

Comment: @ moewe, I already used your suggestions earlier this day, but it also gave me some errors. I then updated to biblatex v3.6 and it is running perfectly. Thank you for your help!